# Map letters from array if the condition is met REACT

Tags: html, reactjs, dictionary, if-statement

I have a state like this one:

```
const [word, setWord] = useState([
    {
      letters: ["r", "e", "a", "c", "t"],
      shows: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    },
  ]);
```

and I want to render a letter if `shows[i] == 1`, else I want to render `"_"`.

How can I do this using map in react (or maybe some other way)? I mean something like this:

```
map((letter, show) => (
    show == 1 ? letter : '_'
))
```

Comment: `map` works on an array, so you'd need to map over either `letters` or `shows`. Are these two arrays always of the same length? Do you want to show the letter that has the same index as the 1 in the `shows` array?

Comment: Why not create an array of objects? `[{ letter: 'r', show: 0 }, { letter: 'e', show:1} etc]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`:

```js
const word = {
  letters: ["r", "e", "a", "c", "t"],
  shows: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
}

console.log(word.letters.map((l, i) => word.shows[i] === 0 ? "_" : l))
```

`word`, in the question, is an array. I would suggest that you make it an object unless that is really required.

Comment: This makes a number of assumptions, which I asked about, and you never answered, @MAXIM7. Had you answered the comment's questions, you would have gotten an answer faster.

Comment: @MAXIM7 If this answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You may try object destructuring also

```
const { letters, shows } = word[0]
console.log(letters.map((l, i) => (shows[i] == 1 ? l : '_')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let words = [
        {
          letters: ["r", "e", "a", "c", "t"],
          shows: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        },
        {
          letters: ["j", "a", "v", "a", "s", "c", "r", "i", "p", "t"],
          shows: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        },
      ]

    /* you can map the words */
                
   words.map(word => 
              console.log(word.letters.map((letter, index) =>
                (word.shows[index] == 1 ? letter : "_")))
```